# Display empty dates in grouping?

Tags: mysql, date, count, group-by

I'm currently using MySQL to count the number of rows created by date for the past week. 
This is a sample of what my Table looks like:
[image: My Table]
With the following SQL query (and considering it's April 20, 2013)

```
SELECT DATE(Date) AS Date,
       COUNT(id) AS Count
FROM notes
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date) + 604800 >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY DAY(Date)
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

I get the following result.
[image: Output]

However, since I'm going through the past week I also want the days where there are no rows like such:

[image: Desired Output]

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the simplest way is

```
select a.*, b.`Count`
   FROM 
   (
   select date(now()) as dt 
   union all
   select date(now()-interval 1 day)
   -- then the same for - 2 day, -3 , etc
   )a
   LEFT JOIN 
   (
     --your query
   )b ON (a.dt = b.`date`)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - however I currently am unable to understand what `a` and `b` represents plus what to do with the part where you say `--your query`. I really do apologize for my lack of SQL knowledge, but can you please explain?

Comment: `a` and `b` are table (inline view/derived table, whatever terminology you prefer for subqueries in `FROM` clause) aliases. Alias names are not important from parsing/execution point of view, but probably it's good to have something more readable than `a`/`b`

Comment: Thank you, the code worked perfectly once I understood what `a` and `b` were